# I am getting an error showing me as Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete

Tags: errors, pdftex, texstudio, amsthm

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]

\documentclass{cambridge7A}

\usepackage{natbib}


\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\rotfloatpagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{multind}\ProvidesPackage{multind}
\makeindex{authors}
\makeindex{subject}


\usepackage[number=none]{glossary}
\makeglossary


\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{conjecture*}{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{prob}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{exer}[theorem]{Exercise}

\newtheorem*{definition*}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}
\newtheorem*{prob*}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{remark*}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{notation*}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{exer*}{Exercise}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\newcommand\cambridge{cambridge7A}


\def\makeRRlabeldot#1{\hss\llap{#1}}
\renewcommand\theenumi{{\rm (\roman{enumi})}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{{\rm (\alph{enumii})}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{{\rm (\arabic{enumiii})}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{{\rm (\Alph{enumiv})}}
\begin{document}
.
.
\end{document}
```

This is the code. The error is

```
Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete. \newenvironment{proof}[1] 
[\proofname]{\par
```

Comment: This is not complete code, so I can't try to compile it, but if you are trying to create a new environment "proof" with @ inside it Latex will give you an error (similarly if you tried to use "&" in text without specifying it with a backslash as a text glyph and not a space delimiter). If you want to use @ to define something you have to begin it with \makeatletter and end it with \makeatother.

Comment: as the error is in the preamble you should be able to post a complete small document of just a few lines that shows the error, please also show the exact error from the log, what you show is not the format of a tex error message. So we don't have the exact error nor any code to test so it is hard to help or guess what is wrong.